# Relative path with javascript, angularJs, and DNN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dotnetnuke, angular-routing

How can the "go back to the root path" function in C#: "~/", be expressed in Javascript if at all. (e.g. "~/myfolder/anotherfolder/file.html").

The problem that I encountered is actually related to DNN, AngularJS and the use of routes. I have a DNN page on which I defined an angular module (call it app). The module's js files are located inside the DNN skin which I named 'mySkin' and defined a variable like so:

```
  var skin path = "/Portals/​_default/​Skins/​mySkin/"
```

and the template's path is:

```
  var template = "/Portals/​_default/​Skins/​mySkin/templates/template.html"
```

The route as:

```
  var routes = {
      main: { templateUrl: template, controller: 'mainController' },
   }
```

With this configuration ng-view is not being populated with anything and i suspect that it is because the DNN page is executed at a route:

```
mydomain.com/services#/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's related but its not a duplication. I believe that many DNN developers will move to using Angular soon. This then might be a common problem. Anyway this post might help them look in the right direction.

Comment: I guess it can help link DNN and this specific problem, which is often hard to do. I'll remove my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking in the wrong direction. Apparently the paths I defined above were perfectly fine. But for some UNKNOWN reason, something was adding zero width spaces to my path. To resolve the issue i used the following code:

```
 skinPath = skinPath.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, '');
```

Which was originally suggested in this StackOverflow question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string
```