# How to identify zero-width character?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 found an unexpected character in my code (error [CS1056](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59k0x971(v=vs.90).aspx))

How can I identify what the character is? It's a zero-width character so I can't see it. I'd like to know exactly what it is so I can work out where it comes from and how to fix it with a find-and-replace (I have many similar errors).

Here's an example. There's a zero-width character between x and y in the quote below:

> x​y

It would be helpful just to tell me the name of the character in my example, but I'd also like to know generally how to identify characters myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, use this website http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%E2%80%8B&preview=entity

> Are you looking for Unicode character U+200B: ZERO WIDTH SPACE?

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Answer (score 11):

I have a little bit of Javascript [embedded within my explanation of Unicode](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer) which allows you to see the Unicode characters you copy/paste into a textbox. Your example looks like this:

[image: Unicode explorer]

Here you can see that the character is U+200B. Just searching for that will normally lead you to http://www.fileformat.info, in this case [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) which can give you details of the character.

If you have the characters yourself within an application, `Char.GetUnicodeCategory` is your friend. (Oddly enough, there's no `Char.GetUnicodeCategory(int)` for non-BMP characters as far as I can see...)

Answer (score 3):

According to similar question: [Remove zero-width space characters from a JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string)

I'd hit ctrl+f (or ctrl+h) and turn on Regexp option, then search (or search-replace) for:

```
[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]
```

I've just tried your example and successfully replaced that zero-width space with "X" mark.

Just please note that this range covers only a few specific characters as explained in that post, not all invisible characters.

edit - thanks to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) I've found a better expression that seems nicely supported in the "find/replace" when Regexp option is turned on:

```
\p{Cf}
```

which seems to matches invisible characters, it successfully hit that one in your example, though I'm not exactly sure if it covers all you'd need. It may be worth playing with whole `{C}`-class or searching for whitespace|nonprintable plus negative match for `{Z}`-class (or `{Zs}`) negation.

Comment: Searching using a regexp should help you find the char. Search and replace should help you replace it with a visible character. If you replace it I suggest replacing it with something unique so it's easier to find the changed text later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the built-in Unicode table:

```
var category = char.GetUnicodeCategory(s[1]);
```

The specific character in your example is in the `Format` category and here is what [MSDN has to say about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Format character that affects the layout of text or the operation of text processes, but is not normally rendered. Signified by the Unicode designation "Cf" (other, format). The value is 15.

To get the character code, simply extract it:

```
char c = s[1];
int codepoint = (int)c; // gives you 0x200B
```

The [unicode codepoint 0x200b](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) is known as "zero width space".