# HTML - How to remove Zero-Width No Break Space

Tags: html, unicode, sitecore

**I have looked at both:**

- [Remove zero-width space characters from a JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string)
- [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)

**The issue:**

[image]

The unicode character comes in the exact same spot every time, between the `.breadcrumbs` and `.hero` divs (*some of the pages do not have an `.actions` container in case you're wondering*).

Using Sitecore 8 (CMS). I have NO IDEA where this is coming from. It only happens on a couple of pages, and I *think* I've narrowed it down to (2) renderings. I followed the advice in one of the (2) blog posts above, and copied the HTML out of my VS, into Notepad++, and re-copied it out of Notepad back into VS. However this is not working, therefore this leads me to believe that somehow this unicode is coming from the CMS.

**My question:**

This site is about to go into production very soon (couple of days now), and I need a quick fix (or this could be the only fix).

1. Would it be optimal (time wise, etc) to check if the page contains
   these (2) elements, `.hero` and `.breadcrumbs`, and then strip out
   the unicode character?
2. Do I search for the text, `&#65279;` or something else? (ie -
   `U+FEFF`, etc)
3. Another way that I'm not thinking of

Comment: Try to open the .cshtml or .ascx file of the component which contains `<div class="hero"` with notepad++. Click `Encoding` in the menu and see if there is `UTF-8-BOM` selected. If not, try other files used on that page.

Comment: I'll try that now - I also asked another dev here and she suggested a HTML tag that isn't properly closed - have any of you experienced this?

Comment: Both files have a dot beside "Encode in UTF-8" in Notepad++

Comment: What about the layout file? Try removing component one by one from the page and see if this character disappears

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my case, I opened up all files that I thought were be an impact into Notepad++, then on each file (in Notepad++), I changed the encoding to `Encode in ANSI`. One of the files had some hieroglyphics on top (line 1). Removed that and saved back to normal encoded state.

Comment: The perfect answer, worked for me 100%...
 THNX