# elixir - replace unicode chars - PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u

Tags: regex, elixir

I am trying to remove invisible characters from string

see [remove-zero-width-space-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string/11305926#11305926)

```
iex> str = "\uFEFF<?xml>"
iex> String.replace(str, ~r/[\u200B\u200C\u200D\uFEFF]/, "")   
** (Regex.CompileError) PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at position 1
    (elixir) lib/regex.ex:171: Regex.compile!/2
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.sigil_r/2
    iex:44: (file)
```

error:
`PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at position 1`

how can I implement the above regex?

Note: When using a string instead regex it works, but for code efficiency I would like to use regex

```
iex(34)> String.replace(a, "\uFEFF", "")
"<?xml>"
```

Comment: Change it to `[\x{200B}\x{200C}\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]`

Comment: iex(44)> String.replace(a, ~r/[\x{200B}\x{200C}\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/, "")      
** (Regex.CompileError) character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at position 8

Comment: Enable `u` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using PCRE to match invisible characters use `\p{C}` property. This includes all invisible characters. For your case the error is due to the notation being used. PCRE doesn't support `\uXXXX` but `\x{XXXX}` and `u` flag should be set.

```
/[\x{200B}\x{200C}\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/u
```

in code:

```
iex(33)> str = "\uFEFF<?xml>"
iex(34)> String.replace(str, ~r/[\x{200B}\x{200C}\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/u, "") 
"<?xml>"
```

Comment: I believe the `u` should be after slash: `r/[\x{200B}\x{200C}\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/u`. If didn't work try `r/(*UTF8)[\x{200B}\x{200C}\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/`