# How to detect invisible (zero-width or whitespace) characters in Unicode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to put unicode characters into the URL but some of them are "invisible" like `U+0000`. However, if I do `String.fromCodePoint(0).length` it is equal to `1`. How do I check that it is an invisible character so I can instead display some other string like it's numeric representation (such as `/unicode/u+0000`) instead of `/unicode/<blank>`.

Currently I have this:

```
var slug = glyph.trim()
  ? glyph.match(/[\?\&\#\/]/)
    ? `u+${unicode}`
    : glyph
  : `u+${unicode}`
```

But it doesn't work for the zero-width (invisible) character U+0000 which has length 1.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: Does it have to be regex...loop through chars and find a zero https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

### Update

> **["Note that there are many more symbols that may not be visible."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11305926/2813224)**

`null` (`\u{0}`) has been added. If you want to detect all whitespaces regardless of width use the meta sequence plus, quantifier `\s+` (`+` quantifier matches one or more of the characters that precedes it.) and an alternate(s) `|` between it and the rest of the regex (`|` is an OR gate).

---

This may be a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you really need to replace zero width characters with **[*Fill in the blank*]** then proceed. If you need a way to copy them and keep the url intact then encode the url with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead.

There's only [four zero width characters](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/zero%20width):

- U+feff - zero width no-break space
- U+200b - zero width space
- U+200c - zero width non-joiner
- U+200d - zero width joiner

In order to use Unicode in RegEx we must use the `u`nicode flag and the following syntax:

> **U+feff**  >>> `\u{feff}`

The following demo will extract the slug from a url and removes the previously mentioned zero width characters. If you wish to replace them with something (I have no idea why it would be useful to do so...), then do the following:

> - **First Parameter:** `url` |String| (required)
> - **Second Parameter:** `slug` |Boolean| (default: `true`) Returns the slug by default. If `false` it returns the full url. Pass explicitly in order to pass third parameter explicitly.
> - **Third Parameter:** `rpl` String or Regex This is the replacement characters. By default it will remove zero width characters without a replacement.

```js
// Each url has a zero width character in the slug
let u200b = `https://example.com/path/to/s​lugs`;
let ufeff = `https://example.com/path/to/slugs`;
let u200c = `https://example.com/path/to/sl‌ugs`;
let u200d = `https://example.com/path/to/slug‍s`;

const getSlug = (url, slug = true, rpl = '') => {
  let regex = /\u{0}+|\u{feff}+|\u{200b}+|\u{200c}+|\u{200d}/gu;
  let string;
  if (slug) {
    string = url.split('/').pop().trim();
    console.log(`Old Length of slug: ${string.length}`);
  } else {
    string = url;
    console.log(`Old Length of url: ${string.length}`);
  }
  let clean = string.replace(regex, rpl);
  console.log(`New Length: ${clean.length}`);
  return clean;
}

getSlug(u200b);
getSlug(ufeff);
getSlug(u200c);
getSlug(u200d);
```

Comment: You cannot determine the properties of a character from its name (alone), this naive approach does not work.

Comment: @daxim Well I apologize for JavaScript's lack of textual savvy. I assumed that the answer be within the scope of the tags [javascript] and [unicode]. I did an update so it's more specific not monolithic which is the gist of said question: *"How to detect invisible (zero-width or whitespace) characters in Unicode in JavaScript?"* (punctuation is mine).

Comment: @daxim Please explain why it doesn't work. I have proof of concept right there (click the blue button that is labelled "Run code script"). The length of each string after execution of the function shows that it is 1 less. Each url had a zero width character and now they don't. It's pretty simple.

Comment: The problem is not with the code, but with your assumption. Op wants characters that show up zero-width. You look for characters whose name contains the literal string zero-width. That finds you only 4 out of 1460. You must test Unicode properties, not names.

Comment: Added `null` which is what OP originally asked for concerning the use of JavaScript and Unicode.

Comment: Using JavaScript to detect [Unicode properties is in Stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes). So when the language itself is severely limited we should give an answer that is in a more capable language that the OP never asked for and probably has little to no knowledge of? BTW one of the Unicode properties is names.

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11305926/2813224)  by the leading authority on such matters, [Mathias-Bynens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens). It's basically the same as mine (I must've previously read his answer and unconsciously regurgitated it with my own code). You should let know him how naive his thinking is as well.

Comment: His answer is correct (for 2012). Quote: "Note that there are many more symbols that may not be visible." Your answer is lacking those. Can you just fix your wrong assumptions and code instead of endlessly complaining?

Comment: You answer in JavaScript. I've updated. Although it's from 2012 it's still pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

> How to detect invisible (zero-width or whitespace) characters

You need to figure out which characters render with column width < 1. I am not aware of a JS module that correctly implements the relevant part of Unicode, so let's use a programming language that is not a constant disappointment when it comes to processing text.

There is not a singular reason for column width < 1 that these characters have in common.

```
› perl -mUnicode::GCString -e'
    for (0..0x1ffff) {
        my $s = Unicode::GCString->new(chr $_);
        print sprintf("U+%04X ", $_) if $s->columns < 1
    }'

U+0000 U+0001 U+0002 U+0003 U+0004 U+0005 U+0006 U+0007 U+0008 U+0009 U+000A
U+000B U+000C U+000D U+000E U+000F U+0010 U+0011 U+0012 U+0013 U+0014 U+0015
U+0016 U+0017 U+0018 U+0019 U+001A U+001B U+001C U+001D U+001E U+001F U+007F
U+0080 U+0081 U+0082 U+0083 U+0084 U+0085 U+0086 U+0087 U+0088 U+0089 U+008A
U+008B U+008C U+008D U+008E U+008F U+0090 U+0091 U+0092 U+0093 U+0094 U+0095
U+0096 U+0097 U+0098 U+0099 U+009A U+009B U+009C U+009D U+009E U+009F U+00AD
U+0300 U+0301 U+0302 U+0303 U+0304 U+0305 U+0306 U+0307 U+0308 U+0309 U+030A
U+030B U+030C U+030D U+030E U+030F U+0310 U+0311 U+0312 U+0313 U+0314 U+0315
U+0316 U+0317 U+0318 U+0319 U+031A U+031B U+031C U+031D U+031E U+031F U+0320
U+0321 U+0322 U+0323 U+0324 U+0325 U+0326 U+0327 U+0328 U+0329 U+032A U+032B
U+032C U+032D U+032E U+032F U+0330 U+0331 U+0332 U+0333 U+0334 U+0335 U+0336
U+0337 U+0338 U+0339 U+033A U+033B U+033C U+033D U+033E U+033F U+0340 U+0341
U+0342 U+0343 U+0344 U+0345 U+0346 U+0347 U+0348 U+0349 U+034A U+034B U+034C
U+034D U+034E U+034F U+0350 U+0351 U+0352 U+0353 U+0354 U+0355 U+0356 U+0357
U+0358 U+0359 U+035A U+035B U+035C U+035D U+035E U+035F U+0360 U+0361 U+0362
U+0363 U+0364 U+0365 U+0366 U+0367 U+0368 U+0369 U+036A U+036B U+036C U+036D
U+036E U+036F U+0483 U+0484 U+0485 U+0486 U+0487 U+0488 U+0489 U+0591 U+0592
U+0593 U+0594 U+0595 U+0596 U+0597 U+0598 U+0599 U+059A U+059B U+059C U+059D
U+059E U+059F U+05A0 U+05A1 U+05A2 U+05A3 U+05A4 U+05A5 U+05A6 U+05A7 U+05A8
U+05A9 U+05AA U+05AB U+05AC U+05AD U+05AE U+05AF U+05B0 U+05B1 U+05B2 U+05B3
U+05B4 U+05B5 U+05B6 U+05B7 U+05B8 U+05B9 U+05BA U+05BB U+05BC U+05BD U+05BF
U+05C1 U+05C2 U+05C4 U+05C5 U+05C7 U+0600 U+0601 U+0602 U+0603 U+0604 U+0605
U+0610 U+0611 U+0612 U+0613 U+0614 U+0615 U+0616 U+0617 U+0618 U+0619 U+061A
U+061C U+064B U+064C U+064D U+064E U+064F U+0650 U+0651 U+0652 U+0653 U+0654
U+0655 U+0656 U+0657 U+0658 U+0659 U+065A U+065B U+065C U+065D U+065E U+065F
U+0670 U+06D6 U+06D7 U+06D8 U+06D9 U+06DA U+06DB U+06DC U+06DD U+06DF U+06E0
U+06E1 U+06E2 U+06E3 U+06E4 U+06E7 U+06E8 U+06EA U+06EB U+06EC U+06ED U+070F
U+0711 U+0730 U+0731 U+0732 U+0733 U+0734 U+0735 U+0736 U+0737 U+0738 U+0739
U+073A U+073B U+073C U+073D U+073E U+073F U+0740 U+0741 U+0742 U+0743 U+0744
U+0745 U+0746 U+0747 U+0748 U+0749 U+074A U+07A6 U+07A7 U+07A8 U+07A9 U+07AA
U+07AB U+07AC U+07AD U+07AE U+07AF U+07B0 U+07EB U+07EC U+07ED U+07EE U+07EF
U+07F0 U+07F1 U+07F2 U+07F3 U+0816 U+0817 U+0818 U+0819 U+081B U+081C U+081D
U+081E U+081F U+0820 U+0821 U+0822 U+0823 U+0825 U+0826 U+0827 U+0829 U+082A
U+082B U+082C U+082D U+0859 U+085A U+085B U+08E3 U+08E4 U+08E5 U+08E6 U+08E7
U+08E8 U+08E9 U+08EA U+08EB U+08EC U+08ED U+08EE U+08EF U+08F0 U+08F1 U+08F2
U+08F3 U+08F4 U+08F5 U+08F6 U+08F7 U+08F8 U+08F9 U+08FA U+08FB U+08FC U+08FD
U+08FE U+08FF U+0900 U+0901 U+0902 U+093A U+093C U+0941 U+0942 U+0943 U+0944
U+0945 U+0946 U+0947 U+0948 U+094D U+0951 U+0952 U+0953 U+0954 U+0955 U+0956
U+0957 U+0962 U+0963 U+0981 U+09BC U+09C1 U+09C2 U+09C3 U+09C4 U+09CD U+09E2
U+09E3 U+0A01 U+0A02 U+0A3C U+0A41 U+0A42 U+0A47 U+0A48 U+0A4B U+0A4C U+0A4D
U+0A51 U+0A70 U+0A71 U+0A75 U+0A81 U+0A82 U+0ABC U+0AC1 U+0AC2 U+0AC3 U+0AC4
U+0AC5 U+0AC7 U+0AC8 U+0ACD U+0AE2 U+0AE3 U+0B01 U+0B3C U+0B3F U+0B41 U+0B42
U+0B43 U+0B44 U+0B4D U+0B56 U+0B62 U+0B63 U+0B82 U+0BC0 U+0BCD U+0C00 U+0C3E
U+0C3F U+0C40 U+0C46 U+0C47 U+0C48 U+0C4A U+0C4B U+0C4C U+0C4D U+0C55 U+0C56
U+0C62 U+0C63 U+0C81 U+0CBC U+0CBF U+0CC6 U+0CCC U+0CCD U+0CE2 U+0CE3 U+0D01
U+0D41 U+0D42 U+0D43 U+0D44 U+0D4D U+0D62 U+0D63 U+0DCA U+0DD2 U+0DD3 U+0DD4
U+0DD6 U+0E31 U+0E34 U+0E35 U+0E36 U+0E37 U+0E38 U+0E39 U+0E3A U+0E47 U+0E48
U+0E49 U+0E4A U+0E4B U+0E4C U+0E4D U+0E4E U+0EB1 U+0EB4 U+0EB5 U+0EB6 U+0EB7
U+0EB8 U+0EB9 U+0EBB U+0EBC U+0EC8 U+0EC9 U+0ECA U+0ECB U+0ECC U+0ECD U+0F18
U+0F19 U+0F35 U+0F37 U+0F39 U+0F71 U+0F72 U+0F73 U+0F74 U+0F75 U+0F76 U+0F77
U+0F78 U+0F79 U+0F7A U+0F7B U+0F7C U+0F7D U+0F7E U+0F80 U+0F81 U+0F82 U+0F83
U+0F84 U+0F86 U+0F87 U+0F8D U+0F8E U+0F8F U+0F90 U+0F91 U+0F92 U+0F93 U+0F94
U+0F95 U+0F96 U+0F97 U+0F99 U+0F9A U+0F9B U+0F9C U+0F9D U+0F9E U+0F9F U+0FA0
U+0FA1 U+0FA2 U+0FA3 U+0FA4 U+0FA5 U+0FA6 U+0FA7 U+0FA8 U+0FA9 U+0FAA U+0FAB
U+0FAC U+0FAD U+0FAE U+0FAF U+0FB0 U+0FB1 U+0FB2 U+0FB3 U+0FB4 U+0FB5 U+0FB6
U+0FB7 U+0FB8 U+0FB9 U+0FBA U+0FBB U+0FBC U+0FC6 U+102D U+102E U+102F U+1030
U+1032 U+1033 U+1034 U+1035 U+1036 U+1037 U+1039 U+103A U+103D U+103E U+1058
U+1059 U+105E U+105F U+1060 U+1071 U+1072 U+1073 U+1074 U+1082 U+1085 U+1086
U+108D U+109D U+135D U+135E U+135F U+1712 U+1713 U+1714 U+1732 U+1733 U+1734
U+1752 U+1753 U+1772 U+1773 U+17B4 U+17B5 U+17B7 U+17B8 U+17B9 U+17BA U+17BB
U+17BC U+17BD U+17C6 U+17C9 U+17CA U+17CB U+17CC U+17CD U+17CE U+17CF U+17D0
U+17D1 U+17D2 U+17D3 U+17DD U+180B U+180C U+180D U+180E U+18A9 U+1920 U+1921
U+1922 U+1927 U+1928 U+1932 U+1939 U+193A U+193B U+1A17 U+1A18 U+1A1B U+1A56
U+1A58 U+1A59 U+1A5A U+1A5B U+1A5C U+1A5D U+1A5E U+1A60 U+1A62 U+1A65 U+1A66
U+1A67 U+1A68 U+1A69 U+1A6A U+1A6B U+1A6C U+1A73 U+1A74 U+1A75 U+1A76 U+1A77
U+1A78 U+1A79 U+1A7A U+1A7B U+1A7C U+1A7F U+1AB0 U+1AB1 U+1AB2 U+1AB3 U+1AB4
U+1AB5 U+1AB6 U+1AB7 U+1AB8 U+1AB9 U+1ABA U+1ABB U+1ABC U+1ABD U+1ABE U+1B00
U+1B01 U+1B02 U+1B03 U+1B34 U+1B36 U+1B37 U+1B38 U+1B39 U+1B3A U+1B3C U+1B42
U+1B6B U+1B6C U+1B6D U+1B6E U+1B6F U+1B70 U+1B71 U+1B72 U+1B73 U+1B80 U+1B81
U+1BA2 U+1BA3 U+1BA4 U+1BA5 U+1BA8 U+1BA9 U+1BAB U+1BAC U+1BAD U+1BE6 U+1BE8
U+1BE9 U+1BED U+1BEF U+1BF0 U+1BF1 U+1C2C U+1C2D U+1C2E U+1C2F U+1C30 U+1C31
U+1C32 U+1C33 U+1C36 U+1C37 U+1CD0 U+1CD1 U+1CD2 U+1CD4 U+1CD5 U+1CD6 U+1CD7
U+1CD8 U+1CD9 U+1CDA U+1CDB U+1CDC U+1CDD U+1CDE U+1CDF U+1CE0 U+1CE2 U+1CE3
U+1CE4 U+1CE5 U+1CE6 U+1CE7 U+1CE8 U+1CED U+1CF4 U+1CF8 U+1CF9 U+1DC0 U+1DC1
U+1DC2 U+1DC3 U+1DC4 U+1DC5 U+1DC6 U+1DC7 U+1DC8 U+1DC9 U+1DCA U+1DCB U+1DCC
U+1DCD U+1DCE U+1DCF U+1DD0 U+1DD1 U+1DD2 U+1DD3 U+1DD4 U+1DD5 U+1DD6 U+1DD7
U+1DD8 U+1DD9 U+1DDA U+1DDB U+1DDC U+1DDD U+1DDE U+1DDF U+1DE0 U+1DE1 U+1DE2
U+1DE3 U+1DE4 U+1DE5 U+1DE6 U+1DE7 U+1DE8 U+1DE9 U+1DEA U+1DEB U+1DEC U+1DED
U+1DEE U+1DEF U+1DF0 U+1DF1 U+1DF2 U+1DF3 U+1DF4 U+1DF5 U+1DFC U+1DFD U+1DFE
U+1DFF U+200B U+200C U+200D U+200E U+200F U+2028 U+2029 U+202A U+202B U+202C
U+202D U+202E U+2060 U+2061 U+2062 U+2063 U+2064 U+2066 U+2067 U+2068 U+2069
U+206A U+206B U+206C U+206D U+206E U+206F U+20D0 U+20D1 U+20D2 U+20D3 U+20D4
U+20D5 U+20D6 U+20D7 U+20D8 U+20D9 U+20DA U+20DB U+20DC U+20DD U+20DE U+20DF
U+20E0 U+20E1 U+20E2 U+20E3 U+20E4 U+20E5 U+20E6 U+20E7 U+20E8 U+20E9 U+20EA
U+20EB U+20EC U+20ED U+20EE U+20EF U+20F0 U+2CEF U+2CF0 U+2CF1 U+2D7F U+2DE0
U+2DE1 U+2DE2 U+2DE3 U+2DE4 U+2DE5 U+2DE6 U+2DE7 U+2DE8 U+2DE9 U+2DEA U+2DEB
U+2DEC U+2DED U+2DEE U+2DEF U+2DF0 U+2DF1 U+2DF2 U+2DF3 U+2DF4 U+2DF5 U+2DF6
U+2DF7 U+2DF8 U+2DF9 U+2DFA U+2DFB U+2DFC U+2DFD U+2DFE U+2DFF U+302A U+302B
U+302C U+302D U+3099 U+309A U+A66F U+A670 U+A671 U+A672 U+A674 U+A675 U+A676
U+A677 U+A678 U+A679 U+A67A U+A67B U+A67C U+A67D U+A69E U+A69F U+A6F0 U+A6F1
U+A802 U+A806 U+A80B U+A825 U+A826 U+A8C4 U+A8E0 U+A8E1 U+A8E2 U+A8E3 U+A8E4
U+A8E5 U+A8E6 U+A8E7 U+A8E8 U+A8E9 U+A8EA U+A8EB U+A8EC U+A8ED U+A8EE U+A8EF
U+A8F0 U+A8F1 U+A926 U+A927 U+A928 U+A929 U+A92A U+A92B U+A92C U+A92D U+A947
U+A948 U+A949 U+A94A U+A94B U+A94C U+A94D U+A94E U+A94F U+A950 U+A951 U+A980
U+A981 U+A982 U+A9B3 U+A9B6 U+A9B7 U+A9B8 U+A9B9 U+A9BC U+A9E5 U+AA29 U+AA2A
U+AA2B U+AA2C U+AA2D U+AA2E U+AA31 U+AA32 U+AA35 U+AA36 U+AA43 U+AA4C U+AA7C
U+AAB0 U+AAB2 U+AAB3 U+AAB4 U+AAB7 U+AAB8 U+AABE U+AABF U+AAC1 U+AAEC U+AAED
U+AAF6 U+ABE5 U+ABE8 U+ABED U+FB1E U+FE00 U+FE01 U+FE02 U+FE03 U+FE04 U+FE05
U+FE06 U+FE07 U+FE08 U+FE09 U+FE0A U+FE0B U+FE0C U+FE0D U+FE0E U+FE0F U+FE20
U+FE21 U+FE22 U+FE23 U+FE24 U+FE25 U+FE26 U+FE27 U+FE28 U+FE29 U+FE2A U+FE2B
U+FE2C U+FE2D U+FE2E U+FE2F U+FEFF U+FFF9 U+FFFA U+FFFB U+101FD U+102E0 U+10376
U+10377 U+10378 U+10379 U+1037A U+10A01 U+10A02 U+10A03 U+10A05 U+10A06 U+10A0C
U+10A0D U+10A0E U+10A0F U+10A38 U+10A39 U+10A3A U+10A3F U+10AE5 U+10AE6 U+11001
U+11038 U+11039 U+1103A U+1103B U+1103C U+1103D U+1103E U+1103F U+11040 U+11041
U+11042 U+11043 U+11044 U+11045 U+11046 U+1107F U+11080 U+11081 U+110B3 U+110B4
U+110B5 U+110B6 U+110B9 U+110BA U+110BD U+11100 U+11101 U+11102 U+11127 U+11128
U+11129 U+1112A U+1112B U+1112D U+1112E U+1112F U+11130 U+11131 U+11132 U+11133
U+11134 U+11173 U+11180 U+11181 U+111B6 U+111B7 U+111B8 U+111B9 U+111BA U+111BB
U+111BC U+111BD U+111BE U+111CA U+111CB U+111CC U+1122F U+11230 U+11231 U+11234
U+11236 U+11237 U+112DF U+112E3 U+112E4 U+112E5 U+112E6 U+112E7 U+112E8 U+112E9
U+112EA U+11300 U+11301 U+1133C U+11340 U+11366 U+11367 U+11368 U+11369 U+1136A
U+1136B U+1136C U+11370 U+11371 U+11372 U+11373 U+11374 U+114B3 U+114B4 U+114B5
U+114B6 U+114B7 U+114B8 U+114BA U+114BF U+114C0 U+114C2 U+114C3 U+115B2 U+115B3
U+115B4 U+115B5 U+115BC U+115BD U+115BF U+115C0 U+115DC U+115DD U+11633 U+11634
U+11635 U+11636 U+11637 U+11638 U+11639 U+1163A U+1163D U+1163F U+11640 U+116AB
U+116AD U+116B0 U+116B1 U+116B2 U+116B3 U+116B4 U+116B5 U+116B7 U+1171D U+1171E
U+1171F U+11722 U+11723 U+11724 U+11725 U+11727 U+11728 U+11729 U+1172A U+1172B
U+16AF0 U+16AF1 U+16AF2 U+16AF3 U+16AF4 U+16B30 U+16B31 U+16B32 U+16B33 U+16B34
U+16B35 U+16B36 U+16F8F U+16F90 U+16F91 U+16F92 U+1BC9D U+1BC9E U+1BCA0 U+1BCA1
U+1BCA2 U+1BCA3 U+1D167 U+1D168 U+1D169 U+1D173 U+1D174 U+1D175 U+1D176 U+1D177
U+1D178 U+1D179 U+1D17A U+1D17B U+1D17C U+1D17D U+1D17E U+1D17F U+1D180 U+1D181
U+1D182 U+1D185 U+1D186 U+1D187 U+1D188 U+1D189 U+1D18A U+1D18B U+1D1AA U+1D1AB
U+1D1AC U+1D1AD U+1D242 U+1D243 U+1D244 U+1DA00 U+1DA01 U+1DA02 U+1DA03 U+1DA04
U+1DA05 U+1DA06 U+1DA07 U+1DA08 U+1DA09 U+1DA0A U+1DA0B U+1DA0C U+1DA0D U+1DA0E
U+1DA0F U+1DA10 U+1DA11 U+1DA12 U+1DA13 U+1DA14 U+1DA15 U+1DA16 U+1DA17 U+1DA18
U+1DA19 U+1DA1A U+1DA1B U+1DA1C U+1DA1D U+1DA1E U+1DA1F U+1DA20 U+1DA21 U+1DA22
U+1DA23 U+1DA24 U+1DA25 U+1DA26 U+1DA27 U+1DA28 U+1DA29 U+1DA2A U+1DA2B U+1DA2C
U+1DA2D U+1DA2E U+1DA2F U+1DA30 U+1DA31 U+1DA32 U+1DA33 U+1DA34 U+1DA35 U+1DA36
U+1DA3B U+1DA3C U+1DA3D U+1DA3E U+1DA3F U+1DA40 U+1DA41 U+1DA42 U+1DA43 U+1DA44
U+1DA45 U+1DA46 U+1DA47 U+1DA48 U+1DA49 U+1DA4A U+1DA4B U+1DA4C U+1DA4D U+1DA4E
U+1DA4F U+1DA50 U+1DA51 U+1DA52 U+1DA53 U+1DA54 U+1DA55 U+1DA56 U+1DA57 U+1DA58
U+1DA59 U+1DA5A U+1DA5B U+1DA5C U+1DA5D U+1DA5E U+1DA5F U+1DA60 U+1DA61 U+1DA62
U+1DA63 U+1DA64 U+1DA65 U+1DA66 U+1DA67 U+1DA68 U+1DA69 U+1DA6A U+1DA6B U+1DA6C
U+1DA75 U+1DA84 U+1DA9B U+1DA9C U+1DA9D U+1DA9E U+1DA9F U+1DAA1 U+1DAA2 U+1DAA3
U+1DAA4 U+1DAA5 U+1DAA6 U+1DAA7 U+1DAA8 U+1DAA9 U+1DAAA U+1DAAB U+1DAAC U+1DAAD
U+1DAAE U+1DAAF U+1E8D0 U+1E8D1 U+1E8D2 U+1E8D3 U+1E8D4 U+1E8D5 U+1E8D6 U+E0001
U+E0020 U+E0021 U+E0022 U+E0023 U+E0024 U+E0025 U+E0026 U+E0027 U+E0028 U+E0029
U+E002A U+E002B U+E002C U+E002D U+E002E U+E002F U+E0030 U+E0031 U+E0032 U+E0033
U+E0034 U+E0035 U+E0036 U+E0037 U+E0038 U+E0039 U+E003A U+E003B U+E003C U+E003D
U+E003E U+E003F U+E0040 U+E0041 U+E0042 U+E0043 U+E0044 U+E0045 U+E0046 U+E0047
U+E0048 U+E0049 U+E004A U+E004B U+E004C U+E004D U+E004E U+E004F U+E0050 U+E0051
U+E0052 U+E0053 U+E0054 U+E0055 U+E0056 U+E0057 U+E0058 U+E0059 U+E005A U+E005B
U+E005C U+E005D U+E005E U+E005F U+E0060 U+E0061 U+E0062 U+E0063 U+E0064 U+E0065
U+E0066 U+E0067 U+E0068 U+E0069 U+E006A U+E006B U+E006C U+E006D U+E006E U+E006F
U+E0070 U+E0071 U+E0072 U+E0073 U+E0074 U+E0075 U+E0076 U+E0077 U+E0078 U+E0079
U+E007A U+E007B U+E007C U+E007D U+E007E U+E007F U+E0100 U+E0101 U+E0102 U+E0103
U+E0104 U+E0105 U+E0106 U+E0107 U+E0108 U+E0109 U+E010A U+E010B U+E010C U+E010D
U+E010E U+E010F U+E0110 U+E0111 U+E0112 U+E0113 U+E0114 U+E0115 U+E0116 U+E0117
U+E0118 U+E0119 U+E011A U+E011B U+E011C U+E011D U+E011E U+E011F U+E0120 U+E0121
U+E0122 U+E0123 U+E0124 U+E0125 U+E0126 U+E0127 U+E0128 U+E0129 U+E012A U+E012B
U+E012C U+E012D U+E012E U+E012F U+E0130 U+E0131 U+E0132 U+E0133 U+E0134 U+E0135
U+E0136 U+E0137 U+E0138 U+E0139 U+E013A U+E013B U+E013C U+E013D U+E013E U+E013F
U+E0140 U+E0141 U+E0142 U+E0143 U+E0144 U+E0145 U+E0146 U+E0147 U+E0148 U+E0149
U+E014A U+E014B U+E014C U+E014D U+E014E U+E014F U+E0150 U+E0151 U+E0152 U+E0153
U+E0154 U+E0155 U+E0156 U+E0157 U+E0158 U+E0159 U+E015A U+E015B U+E015C U+E015D
U+E015E U+E015F U+E0160 U+E0161 U+E0162 U+E0163 U+E0164 U+E0165 U+E0166 U+E0167
U+E0168 U+E0169 U+E016A U+E016B U+E016C U+E016D U+E016E U+E016F U+E0170 U+E0171
U+E0172 U+E0173 U+E0174 U+E0175 U+E0176 U+E0177 U+E0178 U+E0179 U+E017A U+E017B
U+E017C U+E017D U+E017E U+E017F U+E0180 U+E0181 U+E0182 U+E0183 U+E0184 U+E0185
U+E0186 U+E0187 U+E0188 U+E0189 U+E018A U+E018B U+E018C U+E018D U+E018E U+E018F
U+E0190 U+E0191 U+E0192 U+E0193 U+E0194 U+E0195 U+E0196 U+E0197 U+E0198 U+E0199
U+E019A U+E019B U+E019C U+E019D U+E019E U+E019F U+E01A0 U+E01A1 U+E01A2 U+E01A3
U+E01A4 U+E01A5 U+E01A6 U+E01A7 U+E01A8 U+E01A9 U+E01AA U+E01AB U+E01AC U+E01AD
U+E01AE U+E01AF U+E01B0 U+E01B1 U+E01B2 U+E01B3 U+E01B4 U+E01B5 U+E01B6 U+E01B7
U+E01B8 U+E01B9 U+E01BA U+E01BB U+E01BC U+E01BD U+E01BE U+E01BF U+E01C0 U+E01C1
U+E01C2 U+E01C3 U+E01C4 U+E01C5 U+E01C6 U+E01C7 U+E01C8 U+E01C9 U+E01CA U+E01CB
U+E01CC U+E01CD U+E01CE U+E01CF U+E01D0 U+E01D1 U+E01D2 U+E01D3 U+E01D4 U+E01D5
U+E01D6 U+E01D7 U+E01D8 U+E01D9 U+E01DA U+E01DB U+E01DC U+E01DD U+E01DE U+E01DF
U+E01E0 U+E01E1 U+E01E2 U+E01E3 U+E01E4 U+E01E5 U+E01E6 U+E01E7 U+E01E8 U+E01E9
U+E01EA U+E01EB U+E01EC U+E01ED U+E01EE U+E01EF
```

Comment: I didn't see a [perl] tag...is there a framework built on JavaScript that uses perl?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would do the replace:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
        if (stringToFind === stringToReplace) return this;
        var temp = this;
        var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
        while (index != -1) {
            temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
            index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
        }
        return temp;
    };

var s = "A\0Z";
console.log(s.length); // returns 3
console.log(s.charCodeAt(1)); // returns 0
console.log(s.replaceAll("\0", "{NULLCHAR}"));
```

Comment: This answer ignores the important part of the question.